# Mongoose hang waiting for localhost

Tags: localhost, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose on Windows 10, `localhost` is unreliable.
I have tried almost all hosts file combination possible.
I have tried almost all qualified names for `localhost`.

Most of the time it just hangs forever. `ping localhost` works fine.
This is a problem I've had on multiple computer with multiple OS and web server configuration.

```
  Proto  Local Address          Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50847  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50848  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50849  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50850  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50851  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50862  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50863  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50864  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50865  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50873  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50874  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50875  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50877  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50878  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50879  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50880  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50881  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50988  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50989  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50990  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50996  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50997  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50998  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50999  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51004  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51005  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51012  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51013  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51014  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51015  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51018  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51019  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51023  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51024  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51025  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51028  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51029  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51033  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51034  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51035  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51036  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51037  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51042  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51043  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51044  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51045  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51048  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51049  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51051  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50847        XXXXXXX:8080   FIN_WAIT_2
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50847  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50848  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50849  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50850  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50851  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50862  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50863  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50864  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50865  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50873  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50874  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50875  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50877  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50878  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50879  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50880  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50881  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50988  CLOSE_WAIT
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50989  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50990  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50996  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50997  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50998  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:50999  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51004  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51005  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51012  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51013  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51014  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51015  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51018  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51019  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51023  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51024  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51025  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51028  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51029  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51033  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51034  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51035  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51036  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51037  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51042  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51043  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51044  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51045  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51048  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51049  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         XXXXXXX:51051  ESTABLISHED
 [mongoose-free-5.6.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50847        XXXXXXX:8080   FIN_WAIT_2
```